# How to run a command in Linux restricting file access in a certain directory?

Tags: linux, bash

What I want to do is to process some batch jobs involving scripts or programs that may unexpectedly perform destructive operations (like doing recursive delete on the "/" dir). The scripts and programs are written by amateurs, who are very likely to do stupid things.

To prevent my OS from being destroyed, I want to restrict file access permissions on a certain directory for each job. I do not want the job script or executable to be able to write or delete anything outside their assigned directory (including the directories assigned for other jobs, I don't want any job to disturb the result of others).

Currently, I thought of two plans:

One is to use `chroot` on executing the jobs. But when using chroot, I will not be able to access bash utilities or other installed programs such as ffmpeg. This is not acceptable for my script jobs.

The other is to create a user for each job, and run jobs as a certain user. But by this way, I would have to create thousands of users; cleaning up would be a great headache.

I'm pretty much prefer the second idea, but I'm seeking for a way to avoid creating so many users and having to delete those users afterwards.

Comment: Maybe `Docker` would be the right tool for this?

Comment: How are these users going to be identified?  How are you going to know which directory they're allowed to trash and which they aren't?  Which user _is_ going to own the relevant directory tree?  How are you going to protect users from each other if they don't have separate user IDs?  How long are the resources created by each user going to reside on the machine? Some user, and some group, is going to own those files.  You need to ensure that the files that the user can't do damage to anyone else.  And by far the simplest way is to give each user their own user ID.  Anything else is fraught.

Answer (score 0):

Put all the tools you need inside a directory and then chroot into it perhaps?

The second option is fine too. You don't have to create many users. Just one or two and all the scripts can run as them.

Third and probably the best is to spawn off a VM and just ssh into it and run the scripts. If the VM gets ruined, you can always spin up another one.

Answer (score 0):

1. How do your users access your computer?
2. Do they have to be root? because otherwise they won't be able to recursively delete /...

Anyway, if it's through ssh, you could configure a separate write-only chrooted environment, like:

**sshd_config**:

```
AllowGroups trusted users
# all users gets chrooted to a directory
ChrootDirectory /srv/jail
# users from a certain Unix group (let's call it "trusted") get chrooted to /
Match Group trusted
    ChrootDirectory /
```

**fstab**:

```
# mount-bind non sensitive directories (ie.: `/tmp`, `/home`) in read-write
/srv/jail/home            /home            home  bind             0  0
/srv/jail/var/spool/mail  /var/spool/mail  mail  bind             0  0

# you mount-bind sensitive directories in read-only
/usr                      /srv/jail/usr    usr   bind             0  0
/usr                      /srv/jail/usr    usr   bind,remount,ro  0  0
# etc.
```

I would personally advice against Docker...